# How to restart an animation with flutter_animate?

Tags: flutter

I recently started using the package `flutter_animate` and it was love at first sight. But how do I restart an animation when a widget gets rebuilt?

E.g., my widget below animates great

```
Text('Good\nJob!')
  .animate()
  .fadeOut(duration: 2000.ms).scaleXY(duration: 2000.ms, end: 2.0)
```

But when I `setState` and the widget rebuilds, the animation doesn't restart and the text remains faded out. Is there a way to trigger a restart on animations every time a widget rebuilds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AnimatedBuilder` widget provided by Flutter

#### Like this

```js
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _animation,
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Text('Good\nJob!')
      .animate()
      .fadeOut(duration: 2000.ms).scaleXY(duration: 2000.ms, end: 2.0);
  },
)
```

#### Usage

```js
setState(() {
  _animation.value = newValue;
});
```